# Is it possible to print the output of a specific layer of a tensorflow model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I constructed this dataset for binary classification that contains digit 0 vs. digit 6.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np

mnist = datasets.load_digits()
# generate the indices
idx_digit = np.argwhere((mnist.target == 0) | (mnist.target == 6)).flatten()

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    mnist.data[idx_digit].reshape((-1,8,8,1)), 
    mnist.target[idx_digit], test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

y_train[y_train==6]=1
y_test[y_test==6]=1
```

I built a convolutional neural network with keras.

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=1, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling2D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)
])
```

I compiled and trained the model and it works well.

```
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy, 
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), 
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=1, verbose=1)
```

I'd just like to know if it is possible to print the output of a specific layer, e.g.

```
model.layers[0].output
```

In other words, how do I get the output of the convolutional layer for a given input x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the output of the intermediate layer after training a model, you can do

1. Along with the last layer output, if we want to receive the convolutional layer's output (of yours).

```
feature_extractor = tf.keras.Model(
    inputs=model.inputs,
    outputs=[
             model.output,  # < last layer output 
             model.layers[0].output # < your convolution layer output 
    ]
)

x = tf.ones((1, 8, 8, 1))
y, conv_y = feature_extractor(x)
y.shape, conv_y.shape
(TensorShape([1, 1]), TensorShape([1, 6, 6, 1]))
```

2. Also, if we want to get all layers output, then we can do

```
 feature_extractor = tf.keras.Model(
        inputs=model.inputs,
        outputs=[layer.output for layer in model.layers],
    )
    
features = feature_extractor(x); print(len(features))
4
    
for i in range(len(features)):
   print(features[i].shape)
    
(1, 6, 6, 1) < first layer output / conv layer 
(1, 3, 3, 1) < second layer output 
(1, 9) < 3rd and 
(1, 1) < 4th (last layer)
```